# using a smaller project as a git submodule in several other projects - can't make it work

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've seen this question crop up more than once in one form or another around here, which is what made me choose this route. So I have a smallish project (web stuff) which has its own gruntfile and git repository and is under active development. I would like to use the **result** of that development in several other projects, that is, I don't want or need the gruntfile or the sass files etc. However, if there's an update in this shared project, I want to be able to pull and merge those updates into the files in the current project. I also want to make modifications to these files to adapt them to the current project's needs.

The way I understand it is, I should make this a git submodule in any other project I want to have these files. I must say that I am fairly new to git, so far I've been using it for a few personal projects - and loving it -, but nothing collaborative (so no pulling and merging yet), and I feel I still don't really have a good grasp on it.

Anyway I added the shared project (let's call it SUB) as a submodule in the project I'm currently working on (let's call this A). So SUB now exists as a folder in A, and `git status` now lists this folder as `modified`. Doing `git add SUB/` does not change this. And doing `git merge SUB/` just nets me a `merge: SUB/ - not something we can merge`. ?? How do I get updated files from SUB into A? Or am I going about this the wrong way? I also found the subtree merge strategy on SO somewhere, maybe that would be more suitable?

I'm using git v2.1.4, afaik there have been changes to git submodule in v 2.10.1 - not sure if this is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first, `A` and `SUB` are two different repos with their own life.

From the point of view of `A`, `SUB` is just a reference/link to a specific commit in `SUB`.
So when you change something in `SUB`, you need to commit these changes:

```
$ cd SUB/
$ git commit -a -m "Improve SUB framework loading times"
[master f78dc91] Improve SUB framework loading times"
 10 files changed, 228 insertions(+), 28 deletions(-)
$ git push
```

So now you've added a new commit (`f78dc91`) to `SUB`, you can go back to `A` and enter:

```
$ cd ..
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   SUB (new commits)
```

The you need to `git add` these `SUB` changes (i.e. reference to the new commit `f78dc91`):

```
$ git add SUB
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   SUB
```

And then commit:

```
$ git commit -m "A now uses a new version of SUB improving loading times."
$ git push
```

So as you see, committing and pushing your changes in `SUB`, and integrating these changes in `A` are two independent actions that you need to perform if you want `A` to get the changes.

**Other comments**

> git merge SUB/

You can only merge references, that means commits, branches and tags (and obviously only references of the `A` repo) so this command does not make any sense. (You can't merge a file or a directory)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I see I don't really understand the mechanics yet. Where do I push to? Doing `git push` in SUB asks me that as well... I have no remote repositories since I'm doing all my work locally and don't need them.

Comment: Ah then you can ignore the `git push` in my response. Then you only need to perform the `git commit`s. Just be sure you take regular backups of you code then.

Comment: But what will you do when you need `SUB` in `B`? One thing you could do is created a so called _bare_ repository on your drive that you can `push`, `pull`, `fetch` or `clone` from when you also want to have `SUB` in project `B`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I understand this a lot better now and I've managed to set up a submodule by creating a push-to bare repository as you suggested. Still struggling with a few details, but that'll work out. Thank you, again, for your help!